# How to generate fields of views to image a list of points in the sample?

Tags: image-processing, cluster-analysis, imaging

I start with a grid of evenly spaced XY coordinates, with the distance between them determined by the field of view of the imaging system.
[image]

The red dots are the XY coordinates, and the scan area looks like this for a 5x5 grid.

As the system takes images from these XY coordinates, from each image, I detect objects, and compute their centroids (blue dots). [image]

Now, the problem is I want to recompute the fields of view, which are represented by the red dots, such that I image the blue dots most effectively.

Towards that, I tried [MeanShift](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#mean-shift) clustering like this

```
class ObjectClusters:
def __init__(self, album):
    self.objects_album = album

def clusters_from_album(self, bandwidth):
    # take object coordinates
    coords = self.objects_album.get_coords()

    # identify clusters
    ms = MeanShift(bandwidth=bandwidth, bin_seeding=True)
    ms.fit(coords)

    cluster_centers = np.array(ms.cluster_centers_)

    points = []

    for _ in cluster_centers:
        points.append(_.tolist())

    return points
```

Now, here's what the results look in real data. [image] The blue dots are centroids of cells, and the orange dots are centroids of Fields of View. In MeanShift, I give the width/2 of the field of view as the `bandwidth` parameter.

Although it looks like this solution works more or less, from the plot, I was wondering if there is a better approach towards this. I want to be able to get something like this ultimately [image]
which is to compute the optimal number of Fields of View (their centroids) to image my sample.

Comment: I fail to see the connection between the mean shift plot and the goal illustrated in the last image. Are you trying to minimize the number of squares to fully cover the blue dots ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I tried mean shift as one approach, as it is a distance based clustering method. I do not know if mean shift is the way to solve this, but basically, I want to fit minumum number of squares around my points. The squares are the field of view of the imaging system (with a square camera).

Comment: so you want to take pictures _twice_, once in a regular grid, and once more by some mysterious calculation? why? you already have the entire area imaged.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz yes, because 

1. the sample is sparsely populated, and many of the images in the regular grid has no/fewer objects
2. we have an imaging modality, where we shrink the imaging field of view in the camera by half, and project a light component (wavelength or polarization) on the other half of the camera. This makes it important to point the system to the XY coords of objects accurately, otherwise we get low cell numbers with a grid scan
3. I want to image with a low magnification objective (10X) to identify objects, and do the second scan with a high mag objective (100X).

Comment: Maybe have a try with a greedy approach: for every point, find the "fixed-radius near neighbors" (those that fit in a square centered at the point). This can be done with a kD-tree. Then adopt the most populated square and consume the points it contains. Repeat with the remaining points. This is a crude and inefficient approach, but probably better than nothing.

Comment: the math problem is called "set cover". you are looking for 2D set cover. there are various classes of algorithms for this.

Comment: *"geometric set cover" even -- try this again on the stack exchange for math or computer science